# EC2 - Disable CPU Turbo boost technology

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, central-processing-unit

I've got a bunch of EC2 instances - I want to disable a CPU feature on one of them (i.e. turbo boost on CPU).

is this possible to do?

I assume I need BIOS access but I can't see anything about it online.

Amazon don't provide 'technical' support for 'basic' plans.

Any ideas?

If I could even do it at OS level it would be good (Windows Server 2012).

Comment: Do you *actually* have blades with Amazon or just EC2 instances?

Comment: @FrederikNielsen just EC2 instances... is it possible to control CPU level features on EC2?

Comment: Not sure if this helps: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html

Comment: @ceejayoz unfortunately that's only for Linux deployments.

Comment: @Woodstock Right, but it implies it's doable w/o BIOS access (which AWS won't give you).

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you want to disable turboboost? You do understand you're running in a virtualized environment, right?

Comment: Yup of course, I understand it's virtual so I'd need access to physical bios to disable it.

Comment: You _again_ did not answer the "Why?" question.

Comment: See comment on below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but currently only with the largest instances of some the newest families using the Intel Xeon E5-2666 v3:

- c4.8xlarge
- d2.8xlarge
- m4.10xlarge

The EC2 documentation provides examples of how to do this on Linux. Basically it boils down to limiting the maximum sleep state to C1:

```
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-... [...] intel_idle.max_cstate=1
```

And requesting no boosted P-states after boot:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo"
```

For more details see [Processor State Control](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html), particularly the "Baseline Performance with the Lowest Variability" section. On Windows, you might be able to do this via **Power Options** as outlined in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/429326) although that references a consumer version of Windows.

Comment: Thanks, need it for Windows though. Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to everything I've read, including [this page on AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/processor_state_control.html), no you can't. If you want that level of control you need a dedicated server. Even if you have a dedicated server in AWS you won't get BIOS access, you'll probably need to buy a physical server.

Why do you even want this? It helps performance.

Comment: It'll be slower without turbo boost :)

Comment: I'm aware, we have performance SLAs to hit for computational tasks and I need to know the real world impact of TB.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to test it on another type of server. I think even i5 / i7 CPUs have it, that might give you some idea, though Amazon's processors are modified for them by Intel so they could be different.

Comment: Avoiding CPU frequency scaling and limiting how "deep" of a sleep state an idle core may go into can produce a more stable performance, even if at a lower baseline level. This is more important to some applications than extracting the maximum burst performance. Benchmarks are a good use case where you probably want to take control of this.

Comment: @Pavel is a CPU core really likely to go to sleep in a virtualised system, with many operating systems servicing many users?